# proto: file is already registered with different packages

Tags: go, proto, protoc

I have 2 proto compiled under different go packages but when I register them in a a server and run it, I get :

```
panic: proto: file "common.proto" is already registered
    previously from: "github.com/soft/test-platform.go/common"
    currently from:  "github.com/soft/proto-asterix/asterix"
```

Here is common.proto in test-platform repository (in `/api` folder) :

```
syntax = "proto3";
package soft.testplatform.common; // here I do defint a UNIQUE package name !

option java_multiple_files = true;
option go_package = "github.com/soft/test-platform.go/common"; // Here I do define a unique go package name !

message MyMessage{
    string commandId = 1;
}
```

As you can see, the package definition for **go_package** and **package** do not collide with package from github.com/soft/proto-asterix/asterix. Only the .proto filenames are similar (common.proto).

I generate go files with protoc an protoc-gen-go plugin using the following command :

```
protoc \
--proto_path=../test-platform/api/   \
--go_out=./common --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
../test-platform/api/common.proto
```

As per documentation here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#fix-namespace-conflict the package and filename should be appended to check for a registration conflict but it does not seem to be the case here.

Has anyone encountered such behavior ? Do I miss something obvious to resolve this package name collision ?

---

Here is what I tried :

- Adding/removing `package` instruction to `common.proto` file
- Change protoc command to use an absolute (and not relative) `proto_path`

Protoc version : libprotoc 3.15.7
Protoc go plugin version : protoc-gen-go v1.26.0

Comment: This issue has been discussed in the Go bug tracker:  https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1122 yes you can't have files with the same name. It appears to have been fixed very recently. For the record, in previous releases, it used to give just a warning

Comment: How can I know, when I import a generated proto code, which filenmaes were used for .proto files ? Also doesnt it make "package" keyword useless ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct anymore. [This commit](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/commit/21e33cc91079beb975323466e237f2486ea29c10) reverted the "bugfix" as it was different from other gRPC implementations.

My only way to fix this was to rename the file/folder.

Comment: interesting, thanks for sharing, this isn't yet released with 1.28.0, is it?

Comment: It is. It has been released only a few weeks after the previous change. I was very confused when I hit this issue and then found the answer above, so I checked the git history.

Comment: Arf this is bad news it restricts so much proto compilation and usage : having a project import another project that contains generated proto is “natural” and in this case we have no access to the proto files and cannot rename them…

Comment: If you find another fix please provide it here we decided in our team to stay on the fixed protoc gen go release before migrating out to something else.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @[blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen) suggestion, indeed, this was a bug fixed by https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/protobuf/+/301953/

While the next release of protoc-gen-go is out, here is a quick fix for your projects :

## Use the fixed protoc-gen-go :

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@febffdd
```

## Change your imports in your `go.mod` to match

```
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.26.1-0.20210525005349-febffdd88e85
```

You should be good to go !

Comment: It may not even be necessary to use the fixed protoc-gen-go (go install step) and maybe only use the fixed protoc runtime in the projects registering the protoc server can be enough : not tested.

Comment: I had same problem with package name and the proto file name is the same. So I changed the proto file name and folder name as well as package name in the second repo and I still get the same error "file is already registered" although since I changed the file name, the file it mentions doesn't even exist in the second package anymore.  Got any insights?

Comment: as suggested by Antonin, simply updated the dependency in go.mod in the service  and built again, worked!